# Git clone and MAMP directory issue

Tags: git, .htaccess, bitbucket

I am working on a site locally between two machines and hosting my repo on Bitbucket and then my local servers through MAMP.

The initial repo was created on my laptop and them when I pushed it up into the repo everything was working fine. When I take a clone on to my desktop the repo is inside a parent folder.

When I launch mamp on the desktop, the 2nd machine, and set the directory i have problems with my images being displayed and CSS. I've narrowed it down to the .htaccess file not liking the files being an extra level down.

I'm a bit stuck on the best way to solve this to work between the two machines?

- Either put original repo and change the .htaccess for both, but this may cause issues when I deploy to live.
- Look for advice on checking out the repo to my 2nd machine without it being in a parent folder. I tried a few suggestions on the boards but it didn't work.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, it looks like the default (?) action for Git is to create a new directory for the repo you are trying to clone, if you try cloning with an additional parameter (see below) if should skip creating the new directory, and just clone it into the current one instead;

```
git clone [git repo location] .
```

The '.' is important - this tells git to use the current directory, or you could put in a local path here to clone into a specific directory.